# Create/update endpoint returning list of objects

Tags: rest, crud, api-design

I've seen a lot of REST implementation examples.

According to them, create endpoint has several options for response body:

- no body at all;
- id of the created entity;
- created entity JSON.

For example, we have a table with data and create a form on the same page on UI.
And we don't want to reload the full page after creating a new entity.

In this case, we have to call our API two times to correctly update our data:

1. POST to create an entity;
2. GET to get a list of entities.

We can't just add a new entity JSON from the response body for a list on UI e.g. if we have pagination/sorting on the server-side.

Based on this information, I have a question. Could a creating/updating endpoint return a resulted list immediately? Or does it violate some best practices? And why?

We can't avoid a second call to a database, but we can avoid a second request to an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could a creating/updating endpoint return a resulted list immediately?

Yes

> does it violate some best practices?

No

> And why

Because REST is the architectural style of the world wide web.

You `GET` a web page.  It includes a form.  You fill in the fields and submit the form.  What do you get back...?

Another web page.

When you are creating a machine to machine interface, the same basic ideas hold.  There are just a few simple changes

- You probably don't want to use media types that are designed for describing displays for human beings, instead preferring something more compact
- You want stable semantics, because machines aren't as adaptable as humans when it comes to interpreting implicit schema.